# Restarting nodes in a flow test throws an error

Tags: corda

My nodes have a custom configuration file, and the flow of events is as follows:
1. Start my network
2. Run the flow that creates my TokenType
3. Stop the nodes
4. Add the token type identifier to the custom config
5. Start the nodes
6. Now my other flows can read that value from the custom config and do their job

```
// Custom config map
Map<String, String> customConfig = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// Assign custom config to nodes
network = new MockNetwork(new MockNetworkParameters().withCordappsForAllNodes(ImmutableList.of(
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("xxx").withConfig(customConfig),

// Run the network and my flow that creates some value to be stored in the config

// Stop the nodes
network.stopNodes();
// Add new value to custom config
customConfig.put("new_value", someNewValue);
// Start the nodes
network.startNodes();
```

But I get this error when starting the network the second time:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine which flow to use when responding to: 
com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.rpc.ConfidentialRedeemFungibleTokens. 
[com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.rpc.ConfidentialRedeemFungibleTokensHandler, 
com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows.flows.rpc.ConfidentialRedeemFungibleTokensHandler] are all registered 
with equal weight.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple flows present in corda-app?. I got similar error when while trying to override an existing flow. After adding the `flowOverride` in the the node definition under `deployNodes gradle task`, the issue is gone.

Example:

```
node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10004
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10005")
            adminAddress("localhost:10006")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
        flowOverride("com.example.flow.ExampleFlow.Initiator",
                "com.example.flow.OverrideAcceptor")
    }
```

More information on this present in below links: 
https://docs.corda.net/head/flow-overriding.html#configuring-responder-flows
https://lankydan.dev/2019/03/02/extending-and-overriding-flows-from-external-cordapps

Comment: Kalyan, my problem is inside flow tests; not when running the nodes; so `deployNodes` task is not involved here.